# Многопоточность. Что использовать

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В C# есть немало средств для работы с потоками. Это и `Thread` и `BackgroundWorker` и `ThreadPool` и даже `Task` с `async` и `await`. В этом многообразии недолго потеряться. Подскажите пожалуйста что и когда из всего этого использовать а то у меня уже голова кругом от всего этого кружится. Плюс еще Parallel/TPL/ В общем я теряюсь в этом многообразии

Comment: Под какой .NET Framework?

Comment: например .NET 4.5

Comment: Как мне сказали, в моем подобном вопросе, async\await сейчас наиболее приоритетный способ организовать многопоточность. Поэтому могу посоветовать использовать этот метод. Но на MSDN я читал, что с ним эффективно работать, если задачи "тяжелые".

Comment: я думаю, конструкции async/await к "организации" самой по себе многопоточности не сказать, чтобы очень относятся, а лишь поддерживают концепцию асинхронного/неблокирующего исполнения. Хотя и лишними в списке их тоже не назовешь(

Answer (score 13):

Если Вы собираетесь изучать многозадачное программирование, и спрашиваете, в каком порядке следует осваивать всё это многообразие, то я рекомендую такой:

1. Для начала посмотрите на потоки (Thread). Поток — достаточно низкоуровневое понятие, он позволяет запустить параллельные вычисления, но не позволяет простым образом получить результат этих вычислений. Преимуществом потоков по сравнению с классической параллельностью на уровне процессов являются пониженные накладные расходы (разные потоки могут работать с одним и тем же адресным пространством). Однако потоки всё ещё достаточно ресурсоёмки, поскольку требуют около 1мегабайта ОЗУ на каждый поток. На этапе изучения потоков попробуйте освоить синхронизацию потоков через примитивы синхронизации (`Mutex`, `Semaphore` и пр.) и методы `WaitOne`, `WaitAll`. Разберитесь, как можно усыплять потоки, как устанавливать им приоритет, чем отличаются фоновые и нефоновые потоки. Факультатив — изучение коллекций, пригодных для параллельного использования (`System.Collections.Concurrent`).
2. Следующая абстракция — пул потоков (Thread pool). Идеален, когда у вас есть много небольших задач, которые можно запускать параллельно. Вычислительные задачи такого рода встречаются нечасто, а вот асинхронный ввод/вывод хорошо ложится на такой сценарий. Пул потоков реализован на уровне Windows, а .NET использует Windows API. Чтобы пул работал, в Windows пришлось ввести специальное "тревожное" состояние потока. Обычно, заснувший или приостановленный поток не может выполнять никакой работы, но если он заснул или ожидает события в тревожном (alertable) состоянии, Windows может разбудить его для выполнения насущность задачи. На этом этапе попробуйте изучить классы `ThreadPool` и `IAsyncResult`, а также разберитесь с контекстом синхронизации (`SynchronizationContext`).
3. Удобным развитием пула потоков в .NET являются задачи (`Task`). Задачи реализованы в т.н. Task Parallel Library (TPL), и значительно упрощают работу с короткими вычислениями и асинхронным вводом-выводом. По сути это обёртка над IAsyncResult. Также можете поиграться с Parallel LINQ на этом этапе.
4. Наконец, финальным аккордом идут ключевые слова `async`/`await`. Если к этому моменту вы плотно поработали с `IAsyncResult`/`Task`, то никаких проблем возникнуть не должно.

Answer (score 7):

`Thread` для того, чтобы:

- не занимать навсегда поток пула,
- поставить повышенный или пониженный приоритет,
- задать потоку имя, чтобы было удобнее искать его в отладчике.

Во всех остальных случаях другие механизмы будут попросту проще в использовании.

`BackgroundWorker` нужен, чтобы выполнить однократную или повторяющуюся фоновую задачу по запросу пользователя. Главное достоинство - можно "бросить" на форму из тулбокса.

`ThreadPool` - это простой способ быстро и однократно породить дочерний поток для выполнения короткой задачи без взаимодействия с пользователем. Сюда же относится `BeginInvoke` на делегате.

`Task` - это прежде всего абстракция значения, которое будет доступно в будущем - а уже потом способ создания нового потока. Существуют способы создать `Task`, который не будет выполнять никакой работы и потому не создаст нового потока - помните об этом. Фактически, это одно из достоинств задач - то, что они создают новые потоки только при необходимости. Является заменой `BackgroundWorker` и устраняет лапшу из методов `BeginXxx` и коллбеков.

`Task` применим

- для выполнения фоновой задачи, инициированной пользователем, с последующим уведомлением пользователя о результате,
- для "быстрого" распараллеливания кода,
- для выполнения сетевых запросов,
- в качестве примитива синхронизации.

Answer (score 2):

Если под .NET 4.5 - то однозначно Task + async/await.

`Task` - это очень удобная обертка над `ThreadPool` и `Thread`. По умолчанию используется `ThreadPool`, но `TaskCreationOptions` можно задать использование `Thread`.

Пример:

```
th[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  // какие то действия
}
, new CancellationToken()
, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning // Указываем использовать Thread
, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

`BackgroundWorker` - для извращенцев и новичков. Много кода, мало толку. Но знать вы это всеравно должны.

`Thread\ThreadPool` - морально устарело. Используется в старых версиях .NET. Знать в любом случае должны.

Comment: Спасибо но пока больше вопросов чем ответов. Почему Task лучше? Каковы его преимуществ? Почему Backgroundworker для извращенцев и новичков? Почему Thread и Threadpool морально устарели?

Comment: Это очень обширная тема. Никто не будет описывать все плюсы и минусы. Ответа просто не хватит (колл-ва символов). Тут даже статьей не обойдешься. Почитайте учебник. Не один ответ тут не охватит всего спектра за и против.

Comment: ну хотя бы в общих чертах. опишите если знаете

Comment: Pavel Mayorov расписал подробнее. Но всеравно - читайте учебник. Это далеко не полный и подробный ответ. Тема очень обширная.

Comment: @JuniorThree, вы в данном случае добиваетесь того, что ваш вопрос просто закроют. Вы добавили в вопрос еще и Parallel/TPL. Читайте учебник.